# Estimation of time-varying velocity

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cross-correlation, time-varying-covariate

**Objective**:
Estimate the mechanical tension of a cable using the velocity of the waves travelling along it.

**Experimental setup**:
I have a cable in tension equipped with accelerometers. I measure a strong cross-correlation between the sensors which corresponds to waves propagating along the cable.

**Tension measurement**:
I have a model of the wave velocity as a function of the mechanical tension. I can therefore estimate it after finding the wave velocity.
However, the tension of the cable changes (smoothly) over time. So I need to be able to estimate the velocity of the waves as they change over time.
I have tried to address this issue using cross-correlations over sliding windows but the results are not good. Indeed, if I take windows that are too short the velocity estimate is biased by the noise and if the window is too large the velocity obtained is an average velocity over the window.

[image]

Illustration:
(Top) Delays corresponding to the maximum of the cross-correlation for different sliding window sizes. (Bottom) Amplitude of the maximum of the cross-correlation.

**My questions:**
Are there any tools to solve this problem? Do you have any suggestions or reading material to recommend? Maybe about non-stationary signals?